# Is it okay to edit titles of questions by other users to make them more descriptive?

Tags: discussion, editing, titles

Is it okay to edit titles of questions by other users to make them more descriptive, less exaggerated or just  better (eg. capitalization, grammar, spelling)?

Comment: Yes! Please do that! Another point: less TeX = enhanced searchability.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Does than mean I should avoid using TeX in titles? And is it okay to un-TeX titles then? Thank you.

Comment: @AGoogler You should not use _too much_ $\TeX$ in titles. ASCII math is often hard to read, so using MathJax for formulae is fine. But titles consisting only of formulae are undesirable.

Comment: @DanielFischer Okay , I'll keep that in mind. Thank you.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You may want to expand on this point. "A difficult integral" is not a better searchable title than $\int \exp(-x^2)\,dx$, even though it uses less TeX. Google picks up TeX syntax to an extent (much better than the built-in search); I constantly find duplicates by searching for TeX syntax with it.

Comment: An ideal title reveals the key content of the question (not just the topic of the question). The example in pizza's comment above is an example of this. The title "A difficult integral" is a nearly useless title. For that matter, many (most?) of the titles on the front page are not indicative.

Comment: Yes! Titles that are not descriptive are awful "A difficult integral", "A question in topology" should be changed to reflect the actual content of the question. I have a couple of theories as to why people don't do this, titles are often written first before a question is fully formed, people have a "fear" to write titles more than a couple of words, there is probably some psychology similar to how "This one weird trick that ____" works. I bet if I titled something "This one weird trick that solves difficult integrals" I would have a "Famous Question" badge within the hour.

Comment: Haha , thank you @JonasMeyer !

Comment: I don't think we should be thinking about how limited the current search tools are. Before we know it these tools will improved and $\TeX$ won't be a problem. Personally I write titles as if we had perfect search tools. I still prefer text over maths most of the time because math can be written in numerous different ways while text has more limited options.

Comment: "But titles consisting only of formulae are undesireable" has less to do with searchability than with usability problems - *some* normal text in the title is required for proper navigation and such

Answer (score 12):

I'm surprised this doesn't have an answer yet. Yes, it's okay, and even encouraged.

More or less the same rules apply as when editing the body of a post; in particular, don't make drastic changes to the meaning of the question. And the title should reflect the question that is more fully expressed in the body of the post.

Comment: Yes "the same rules apply" ... in particular, do it with restraint.  If there are opinions on both sides of a change, leave it the way the OP did it.  For example don't correct spelling *colour* to *color* or vice-versa.